# How does a BST height algorithm count?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

```
int BianaryTree<T>::height(Node<T>* A){
    root = A;
    if(root==nullptr){
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int lHeight=height(root->left); //how is int counting here?
        int rHeight=height(root->right);
        return max(lHeight, rHeight)+1;
    }
}
```

So from what I understand this is a standard Bianary Search Tree height algorithm. My main question is how storing the recursd function in an int variable is "counting" the height of the tree? As far as I can tell all this function is returning is 0.

Comment: because each call is essentially going to end up calling the return max(lHeight, rHeight)+1 and use that value which is an integer

Comment: How solid are you on recursion and recursive problem-solving? I'm wondering if this is a question about this particular piece of code or whether this is a more general question about how recursion works.

Comment: @templatetypedef I am in the process of learning recursion, so if you think I am missing something more generally feel free to fill me in.

Comment: You may want to do a quick search for a simpler recursive function, like one that computes the length of a string or one that computes factorials or Fibonacci numbers, and aim to start there. You're correct that this function sometimes returns 0, but that only kicks a 0 one level higher up in the chain, not necessarily all the way up to the caller. Seeing a simpler example that doesn't require a BST traversal might be helpful for better understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each recursive branch will eventually result in a return value of zero, but it then returns the maximum of the left and right heights plus 1. That plus 1 is critical, without that the return value of the entire recursion would indeed be zero but with it you get the height you expect.

Imagine a tree like the following:

3
 2  4
1

with the children of 1 2 and 4 (not shown) assumed to be null. height(node_1->left) and height(node_1->right) would both be 0 but height(node_1) would be max(height(node_1->left), height(node_1->right)) + 1, that is 1. The rest follows from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this cleared things up!